# Does anyone know Vic Mignogna's (Edward Elric's VA) email address?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, voice-acting

I heard he replies to people who email him and I will love to have the privilege of emailing him. Does anyone know his email? And if he's ever replied to your emails, don't be afraid to tell!

Comment: This kind of question not only has nothing to do with anime or manga, but also would start the a similar question. Soon we will see similar questions asking every seiyuu's email address.

Comment: Yeah, I dunno about this... questions about the professional work of industry figures (voice actors, directors, writers, artists, whatever) is certainly fair game, but I feel that asking for contact info is a bit gauche.

Answer (score 5):

Looking Vic Mignogna up gives me [his website](http://www.vicsworld.net/). [His contact page](http://www.vicsworld.net/contact.htm) lists his email and also has a [mail-to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) link, although the linked email and the email listed are different from each other.

Mignogna is also on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/vicmignogna), so I suppose you could also tweet at him.

I've no idea whether he usually responds to general emails; I don't watch English dubs much and also rarely consciously follow voice actors.